# AutoMapper Questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have a couple questions about AutoMapper.

1) I have a class named Category and a View Model named CategoryViewModel. Do I need to create mappings for each direction?

Mapper.CreateMap(Of Category, CategoryViewModel)
Mapper.CreateMap(Of CategoryViewModel, Category)

2) How do I map collections? I have a CategoryListViewModel that has a single property of IEnumberable(Of CategoryViewModel). I wan to populate those from my service that return IQueryable(Of Category)?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You only have to define the mapping one time. AutoMapper is smart enough to figure out how to map from both directions
2. AutoMapper is smart enough to know how to map to collections once you've registered your type mappings by calling `.CreateMap()`. So you don't have to create a type mapping for collections of your mapped types. AutoMapper will traverse your collections and map each object contained within.

To have AutoMapper map to a list, simply call `List<TypeTo> destination = Mapper.Map<List<TypeFrom>, List<TypeTo>)(sourcObject);`

In VB that may look like the following source, which I ran through a C# to VB.NET converter:

```
Mapper.Map<List<TypeFrom>, List<TypeTo>)(sourcObject);
```

Comment: For #1, I've just created a map only for entity to dto. Then I tried to map back an instance of the dto to an entity, but it didn't work: "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping".

Comment: If you have properties in your entity object that aren't in your DTO, then you probably will need to define a mapping as well. What was the full error message?

Comment: Actually you're probably right, you might need to add a registration for both directions, even if all properties were the same between both types...which they probably aren't I imagine.